# Problem using calligra font with lettrine

Tags: lettrine, calligraphy

I'd like to use the calligra font with lettrine, but lettrine seems to cut off a part of the letter W.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Story}

\lettrine[lines=3, loversize=0.25, findent=1.5em]{\calligra W}{o}\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image: w with right part missing]

When I add a single quote, it does show the entire letter W, but with the single quote which isn't ideal.

```
\lettrine[lines=3, loversize=0.25, findent=1.5em]{\calligra W'}{o}\blindtext
```

[image: w with quote]

Is there any way to solve this? Thanks in advance for an answer.

Comment: Which TeX distribution, and which TeX format, do you use? The reason I ask is that I am unable to reproduce the problem on my system (MacTeX2015/pdfLaTeX).

Comment: In TexLive 2015 it happens!

Comment: I use the texlive 2013.20140215-1 as provided by Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: This is not a problem of `lettrine`. If you type `{\calligra W}` or `\textcalligra{W}`. The same problem happens.

Comment: The first problem seems to be due to the previewer. Try with another one and report, please.

Comment: I was going to say I couldn't reproduce the problem, but it seems others have done it already.  cacamailg, I'm also running TeXLive 2015, and the Calligra "W" looks fine.  Checked in both xpdf and okular.

Comment: egreg is right: mupdf displays the whole letter, atril doesn’t. FontForge reports “Missing Points at Extrema” for W; I wonder whether this could be throwing off some viewers?

Comment: I’m abandoning my missing-points-at-extrema theory: A, G, H, K, N, T, and V are also cut off, but FontForge doesn’t complain about those glyphs.

Comment: The wrong-W example in the picture was created using pdflatex. I now also tried latex > dvips > ps2pdf, which gives a faultless result. It seems that it is a problem in pdflatex, although I don't know anything about this technically. Thanks for your answers!

Comment: I reproduced the problem with `luatex` but not with `xetex`.  However I compile the example, the problem affects only some PDF viewers: atril (much like evince, which I no longer have for testing), apvlv, and zathura. I  don’t know what those viewers have in common, but the error seems to be theirs.

Comment: I don't see a problem with TeX Live 2015, up to date today, Mac OS X. Can you post a full log?